# Selecting the last-child of the last-child

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm having a little trouble selecting the last child of the last child with css.

A sample of what I have is:

```
<div class="X">
    <div class= "A">
        <div class="B"></div>
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="D"></div>
    </div>
    <div class= "A">
        <div class="B"></div>
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="D"></div>
    </div>
    <div class= "A">
        <div class="B"></div>
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="D"></div>  <!-- This is the one I want to select -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been playing around trying to select only the last div with class "D" and just can't. I feel like I've just got to be missing something simple.

The end goal is to not display it, but I always end up either not displaying any of the "D" elements, or not displaying the last "A" element.

Could someone show me how to do this?'

EDITED: I forgot the top level element. Added the X div to clarify exactly what I have.

Comment: Well, i would add an ID to the div you want <div class="D" id="Div3"></div> so you can identify it easily, on this page you will find several css selectors you may find useful: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: :last is not a valid CSS selector... should use :last-child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
.A:last-child div:last-child {
    //rules
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I posted the incorrect HTML at first and you got in with an answer before I fixed it. Your answer would have been correct had I not posted wrong.  Edit: checked after fixing, still correct. Thank you! I voted your answer as useful, but someone else was first so I feel obligated to select theirs as accepted.

Comment: @MikeN I don't see any earlier questions than tymeJV's.

Comment: Yes you are correct. There was a 1 minute difference and I derped. Saw 1 minute less and defaulted to lower == faster. I gave him the accepted mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.A:last-child div:last-child {
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VK5tD/)

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle Link, that will definitely be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector:

```
div.A:last-child div.D { ... }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/R378R/)

Comment: `div.D:last-child` there is only one `D`